# How to handle localization of audio files or other assets in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, localization

I have some audio files that contain speech in the specific language. Let's say default is english and I also have french audio files. In native Android I have different folders for these files in my res folder. For example raw (contains default files) and raw-fr (contains french).
In code I only call play(sound.mp3) and Android uses the correct file for the language that this user has chosen.

**Is there already a similar way for this on Flutter?**
(It is not a big problem to do this by myself, but of course it would be easier if Flutter has some mechanic for this. I am planning to create folders in my assets folder for each language and create a class that is setting the prefix depending on users device language)